# C++ VTK application UI automation

Tags: python, c++, windows

My question is how to expose data in c++ application to python in runtime?

Here is the background:

I have a DICOM viewing application to test and UI automation testing is required. The windows and controls are created by WPF and can be well recognized by pywinauto. However, the image display window and all elements inside are painted by vtk and other c++ code, so basiclly they are not controls so cannot be recognized by pywinauto.

What I want to do is to implement a set of functions in c++ code to expose some information of the painted elements, such as location, size, color, text, etc., to python. Then python script running outside the c++ app can get those information.

Is that possible and how to implement?